# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError....couldn't find "libaacdecoder.so"

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-ndk, arm

so I've spent the last 3 days going crazy trying to figure out what is causing the following error on my streaming radio app.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: ca.threeohsixmedia.radio, PID: 24294

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/ca.threeohsixmedia.radio-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libaacdecoder.so"                                                                           
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:984)                                                                              
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1562)                                                                                                         
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.loadLibrary(Decoder.java:188)                                                                              
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.create(Decoder.java:222)                                                                              
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.Decoder.create(Decoder.java:199)                                                                              
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.createDecoder(AACPlayer.java:508)                                                                              
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.MultiPlayer.createDecoder(MultiPlayer.java:91)                                                                              
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer.<init>(AACPlayer.java:130)                                                                              
at com.spoledge.aacdecoder.MultiPlayer.<init>(MultiPlayer.java:81)                                                                              
at co.mobiwise.library.radio.RadioPlayerService.getPlayer(RadioPlayerService.java:424)                                                                              
at co.mobiwise.library.radio.RadioPlayerService.onCreate(RadioPlayerService.java:238)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3192)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1568)                                                                              
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)                                                                              
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)                                                                              
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)                                                                              
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                              
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)                                                                              
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

The strange thing is that the app works fine in the android studio Google Pixel emulator but not on the actual Google Pixel hardware. All my files are in the right location.

I tried [this solution](https://medium.com/mobiwise-blog/unsatisfiedlinkerror-problem-on-some-android-devices-b77f2f83837d) and many others with no luck. I have no idea where else to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you load the library ? Where did you put them?

Answer (score 0):

One Suggestion as i also faced the same problem once. Please check that the Package name is without any space. Apart from that if you are integrating SDK then do not change the package name of supporting class if any that the developer have used. You are free to change the package name of Activity Class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you add this code in app/build.gradle ?

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes that is in there. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. Apparently using abiFilters doesn't work if the build.gradle file is in the lib folder.